# About calling methods from a synchronized block

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, synchronization, thread-safety

Is synchronizing a method equivalent to letting only one thread to evaluate it until it's out of scope including inner method calls?

For example:

```
public synchronized void foo(){

    if(critical condition){
        bar();  // can influence the above condition
    }
    baz(); // can influence the above condition
}
```

Can two threads be in `bar` (suppose it's called only from here)?

What if `baz` can be called from another place in the code other than `foo`, can two threads be in it then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an equivalent way of writing your code:

```
public void foo(){
    synchronized (this) {
        if(critical condition){
            bar();  // can influence the above condition
        }
        baz(); // can influence the above condition
    }
}
```

Because synchronized methods actually synchronize their bodies using `this` as the lock object.

So, can two threads be executing `foo()` at the same time or `bar()` at the same time? Sure, if they are executing the `foo()` or `bar()` of different objects.

Also, the call to `baz()` is not synchronized at all, so even any two threads can run the `baz()` of single object at the same time, as long as at least one of them is invoking it from outside `foo()`.

These two resources are useful for understanding what synchronization does and doesn't do in Java:

- [Synchronized Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)
- [Intrinsic Locks and Synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)

I recommend you check those pages because there are some pieces of information that are not too obvious until you check them. For example:

- Two different threads cannot execute at the same time two **different** synchronized methods of a single object.
- A single thread can be executing two different synchronized methods of the same object (called *Reentrant Synchronization*)

Comment: So it looks like if I'll sync `bar()` and `baz()`, one thread will take `this` as the lock and use it through both `bar`, `baz` till the end of `foo` and only one thread?

Comment: I saw those links before I asked the question, they don't have an example of a method call from a sync block...

Comment: The lock that a thread acquires when entering `foo` will remain with the thread until exiting `foo`, even if inside `foo` you are calling other methods. While the thread is inside `bar` it still is retaining the lock because `foo` is still in execution.

Comment: Got it, and I could just sync `baz` so another thread won't go into it at the same time.

Comment: Yeap, that's how it works. Synchronizing `baz` avoids another thread will enter to `baz` or `foo` for this same object if your original thread is in either `baz` or `foo`.

Answer (score 5):

> Can two threads be in bar (suppose it's called only from here)?

Yes, provided they are using different objects, or one is `wait()`ing.

> What if baz can be called from another place in the code other than foo, can two threads be in it then?

Yes, placing `synchronized` on one method has no effect on methods which are not synchronized.

Comment: By different object you mean a different instance of the class `foo` is in? Also, would placing a lock on `foo` make only one thread to be in `bar` or `baz`?

Comment: @kuhaku you can have multiple instances of the class which implements `foo()` if you have only one instance and only one method which can call `bar()` and `baz()` then only one thread can be in these methods (unless you use wait())

Comment: More than one method can call `baz()` and there are several instances of the enclosing class but they act on themselves not on eachother...

Comment: @kuhaku in which case any number of threads could be running that method. Imagine you have two cities, each with an impregnable gate, but no walls. Can two people get into a city at the same time?

Comment: So if there are several instances of the same class, two threads can go to the same instance but if the class is a singleton, only one?

Comment: @kuhaku Each object has one lock (Unless it's a `Lock`) if you have two instances, two threads can hold a lock on each one and be in the same method (but with a different instance) What is important is how the objects are locked or not. You don't lock methods. Locking an object has no effect on code which doesn't use synchronized.